# ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined: how to find the column

Tags: oracle, ora-00918

I'm getting the classic error:

> ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Usually, I know how to solve it but my problem now is that I'm working with a 700 row query.

Is there a way to identify the column?

Comment: nono 700 row of SQL code (about 100 column)

Comment: What client are you using? Most will direct you to the correct line (or close enough).

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer, but there is no sign of the row with the error

Comment: A 700 row query is usually a sign that something is very wrong in the logic.

Comment: i know, don't have time to rearrange the logic, the query is not mine i just have to fix it, so the only thing i need is to know if there is a way to identify the ambiguous column

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried to do a binary search?

e.g.

If your original query looks like

```sql
Select  col1 
       ,col2
       ,col3
       ,col4
from MyTable
```

1. you can start with commenting the 2nd half

```sql
Select  col1
       ,col2
       /*,col3
       ,col4 */
from MyTable
```

2. If you still get the error, run the query again commenting some column from the other half:

```sql
Select col1
       /*,col2 */
      ,col3
      ,col4
from MyTable
```

If you still get an error then your problem is with `col1`, otherwise you need to change `col2`.

Comment: Really Oracle should come to the party and give better error messages.

Comment: Also the above is probably not going to work if you have multiple ambiguously defined columns. There goes my day of productivity.

Answer (score 6):

The ambiguous column error message indicates that you have joined two (or more) columns in your query which share the same column name.

The proper way to solve this is to give each table in the query an alias and then prefix all column references with the appropriate alias.  I agree that won't be fun for such a large query but I'm afraid you will have to pay the price of your predecessor's laxness.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, you can use [all_tab_cols](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_1179.htm) to query the columns names of your tables. The following query will return the common column names between *TABLE1* and *TABLE2*. Then you just need to prefix those common columns instead of all 100 column references.

```
select column_name from all_tab_cols
where table_name='TABLE1' and owner ='OWNER1' 
and column_name in (
select column_name from all_tab_cols
where table_name='TABLE2' and owner ='OWNER2')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check common columns by using :

```
 select COLUMN_NAME from ALL_TAB_COLS where TABLE_NAME = 'tablenamefirst'
intersect
select COLUMN_NAME from ALL_TAB_COLS where TABLE_NAME = 'tablenamesecond';
```

Answer (score 0):

For posterity's sake:
I had this issue when I selected columns TABLE1.DES and TABLE2.DES in a query without aliasing the result.  When I ran it alone my SQL editor turned these into DES and DES_1, no complaint.

However when I turned the same query into a subquery

```
SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, b.*
from TABLE3 a
INNER JOIN (
--that query as a subquery
) b
on a.PK=b.FK`
```

it threw the same ORA-00918 error message you described.  Changing the SELECT in my subquery to

`SELECT TABLE1.DES AS T1_DES, TABLE2.DES AS T2_DES ...`

fixed the issue.